# Python: editing a series of txt files via loop

Tags: python

With Python I'm attempting to edit a series of text files to insert a series of strings. I can do so successfully with a single txt file. Here's my working code that appends messages before and after the main body within the txt file:

```
filenames = ['text_0.txt']

with open("text_0.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(filename) as infile:
            header1 = "Message 1:"
            lines = "\n\n\n\n"
            header2 = "Message 2:"
            contents = header1 + infile.read() + lines + header2
            outfile.write(contents)
```

I'm seeking some assistance in structuring a script to iteratively make the same edits to a series of similar txt files in the directory. There are 20 or similar txt files are structured the same: `text_0.txt`, `text_1.txt`, `text_2.txt`, and so on. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are they all in 1 directory

Comment: Yes, all in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

to loop through a folder of text files, you need to do it like this:

```
import os


YOURDIRECTORY = "TextFilesAreHere" ##this is the folder where there's your text files

for file in os.listdir(YOURDIRECTORY):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    with open(YOURDIRECTORY  + "/" + filename, "r"):
        ###do what you want with the file
```

Comment: Instead of ```with open(YOURDIRECTORY  + "/" + filename, "r")```, do ```with open(os.path.join(YOURDIRECTORY,filename), "r")```

Comment: thanks @Sujay, that is more cleaner, I agree

Answer (score 1):

**If you already know the file naming then you can simply loop:**

```
filenames = [f'text_{index}.txt' for index in range(21)]

for file_name in filenames:
    with open(file_name, "w") as outfile:
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(filename) as infile:
            header1 = "Message 1:"
            lines = "\n\n\n\n"
            header2 = "Message 2:"
            contents = header1 + infile.read() + lines + header2
            outfile.write(contents)
```

**Or loop the directory like:**

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
      #do something , like check the filename in list
```

Comment: OP has mentioned 20 files, My intention is just to give the understanding with respect to that.